# How to sort JSON array by input string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a large JSON array that can be found [here](https://api.covid19api.com/summary). I would like to sort this data by the value the user inputs in the input field and save it into a variable.

```js
function submit() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;

  fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      //code for sorting countries goes here
    })
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Country Name">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Again, what I want to do here is have the name of the country entered in the input field by the user, for example, India. In the submit function, I want to fetch the data and sort it as shown by the comments. This sorted data will then be stored in another array in the array form. How do I do this?

Basically what I want is when the user searches for a country, for example, India, the data for India is stored in a variable.

```js
var userInput = [{
      "Country": "India",
      "CountryCode": "IN",
      "Slug": "india",
      "NewConfirmed": 9471,
      "TotalConfirmed": 236184,
      "NewDeaths": 286,
      "TotalDeaths": 6649,
      "NewRecovered": 4783,
      "TotalRecovered": 113233,
      "Date": "2020-06-06T14:58:35Z"
    }]
```

Comment: What have you tried? share your code here

Comment: I don't know how to do this that's why I'm asking.

Comment: "Sorting" by an input doesn't make any sense. Do you want the selected country as first? And what about the others? If when sorting the user writes `India` how can you know which one between `Algeria` and `Angola` comes first?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I want the input field to appear first, alternatively, I would like the `India` data to be stored in a variable so I could use it for later purposes.

Comment: @robloxGamer3029 You can first look how `sort` works. Also I'm not sure what is your expected output. But I assume this is what you need. `response.Countries.sort((a,b)=>(b.Country.startsWith('I')) - (a.Country.startsWith('I')));`

Comment: No problem, I made an edit in my post which will hopefully clear things up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this way:

```js
function submit() {
      let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;

      fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          let countryList = data.Countries;
          for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++){
            if (countryList[i].Country == inputValue){
              // Append the sorted data in your desired  variable.
                console.log(countryList[i]);
               break;
            }
          }
        })
    }
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Country Name">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is filter the data which you can do this way.

```
var inputValue = "Al"
var filterdData = data.Countries.filter(i=> i.Country.includes(inputValue));
```

However, if you want to sort, you can do this way. Prioritising selecting country based on input value:

```js
 
 var data = {
  "Global": {
    "NewConfirmed": 101781,
    "TotalConfirmed": 6829314,
    "NewDeaths": 3800,
    "TotalDeaths": 402636,
    "NewRecovered": 131192,
    "TotalRecovered": 3000504
  },
  "Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "Afghanistan",
      "CountryCode": "AF",
      "Slug": "afghanistan",
      "NewConfirmed": 915,
      "TotalConfirmed": 18969,
      "NewDeaths": 9,
      "TotalDeaths": 309,
      "NewRecovered": 177,
      "TotalRecovered": 1762,
      "Date": "2020-06-06T14:38:12Z"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Albania",
      "CountryCode": "AL",
      "Slug": "albania",
      "NewConfirmed": 15,
      "TotalConfirmed": 1212,
      "NewDeaths": 0,
      "TotalDeaths": 33,
      "NewRecovered": 12,
      "TotalRecovered": 910,
      "Date": "2020-06-06T14:38:12Z"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Algeria",
      "CountryCode": "DZ",
      "Slug": "algeria",
      "NewConfirmed": 104,
      "TotalConfirmed": 9935,
      "NewDeaths": 9,
      "TotalDeaths": 690,
      "NewRecovered": 156,
      "TotalRecovered": 6453,
      "Date": "2020-06-06T14:38:12Z"
    }
  ]
};
 var inputValue = "Algeria"
 data.Countries.sort((a,b)=>{
      if(a.Country === inputValue && b.Country !== inputValue){
       return -1
      }
      if(a.Country !== inputValue && b.Country === inputValue){
       return 1
      }
      return a.Country.localeCompare(b)


    });
    
    console.log(data)
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what this means?

Comment: when stored in a JS variable, a.country - b.country as shown returns `NaN`.

Comment: I'm not trying to compare if the value of the country matches the input field. Please look at the post again to understand what I'm doing

Comment: Basically what I want to do is search the value of the input field in the data and have the data associated with the country which the user searched in a variable.

Comment: I just want to filter the results and store them into the variable based on the input value. I see that you have return `1`, `-1`, and `0`, Instead of that I want to save the data associated with the country into a variable by filtering all the data.